# Formatting a USB Drive for use on Windows with FAT/exFat

Tags: hard-drive, windows, disk-utility, exfat, fat32

I would like to use my USB stick to transfer files to a Windows machine. [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-il/guide/disk-utility/dskutl1010/mac) says to use FAT or exFAT. However, the Disk Utility only offers APFS variants. (See screenshot.) How do I format a USB stick for Windows?

(Macbook Pro Big Sur 11.6.1)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to format the volume, not the entire drive.
This isn't obvious, as Apple chooses to present the user with only a volume view by default.

[image]

View menu > Show all Devices or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>  will switch to device view, from where it all becomes more apparent.
You then choose the device itself, rather than any of the volumes/partitions on it & all the format options will be open to you.

[image]

Make sure to also select Scheme: MBR for best compatibility with other devices/OSes.

Answer (score 0):

In the Disk utility window, push cmd + 2 key and select the physical USB key, then erase and you will be able to select all options.